# How to process a HTTPS get in Java

Tags: java, http, https

So I'm currently doing a project where we have to accept and process HTTP requests, which I have done successfully.
There's an optional task of also accepting HTTPS requests, which I'm confused as to how I'd go about that, preferably using standard Java.

For regular HTTP, I'm using a regular ServerSocket accept(), then reading from the socket through an InputStreamReader in its InputStream, like so:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Problem is, when I try with HTTPS, the message I can read on the first line of the HTTPS GET is just garbled characters. Is there a way to process this as well?

Comment: You want a `SSLSocket`.

Comment: More exactly you want to `accept` on an `SSLServerSocket` which was created using a keystore (or at least `KeyManager`) containing a suitable key and certificate for a server, which produces an `SSLSocket` in the same way `ServerSocket.accept` produces a plain `Socket`. For test/debug purposes you can use `keytool -genkeypair` to generate a keystore containing a key and selfsigned cert if you don't have and can't or don't want to get a real cert.